# Why does applying uk-width-1-1 effect child divs of uk-grid but not nested divs of child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, getuikit

Why is 100% width not applied in this implementation (where the class `uk-width-1-1` is applied to nested div of child of grid container):

```
<div uk-grid>
<!-- column 01 -->
    <div>
        <!-- this will be a row, stacked -->
        <div class="uk-width-1-1 mine">Row 01</div>
        <!-- this will be a row, stacked -->
        <div class="mine">Row 02</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However it is applied when implementing like this (where the class `uk-width-1-1` is applied to child of grid container):

```
<div uk-grid>
<!-- column 01 -->
    <div class="uk-width-1-1">
        <!-- this will be a row, stacked -->
        <div class="mine">Row 01</div>
        <!-- this will be a row, stacked -->
        <div class="mine">Row 02</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can see how to achieve the effect I want, but would like to know what the logic is behind it so I can understand it better.

jsFiddle showing both implementations is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/L0npvc57/).

**Edit:**

I can replicate the behaviour using just flex styles - so I need to figure out why can child div be 100% and nested divs cannot?

```html
<!-- nested div is only the width of the content -->
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
  <div>
    <div style="width:100%; background: red">Item 1</div>
    <div style="width:100%; background: red">Item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- if applied to child div, is 100% width of parent -->
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
  <div style="width:100%">
    <div style="background: red">Item 1</div>
    <div style="background: red">Item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- if not using flex at all, nested divs are 100% width of parent -->
<div>
  <div>
    <div style="width:100%; background: red">Item 1</div>
    <div style="width:100%; background: red">Item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Perhaps a `flex item`, which is any immediate child div in a `flex container`, by default is the width of its content, therefore nested divs, if given `width: 100%`, faithfully represent 100% of their immediate parent container's width and not the top level container where `display: flex` is defined?

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer I can add to have it accepted?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does applying `uk-width-1-1` effect child divs of uk-grid but not
>   nested divs of child?

Children of *flex items* is not part of the Flexbox. It is only children of a *flex container* (an element with `display: flex`) that is (or as you called them, *immediate* children), so your inner most `div`'s is normal block level elements and will not respond to the set class `uk-width-1-1`, their parent will though, as in your second sample.

When it comes to Flexbox, one can, simplified, say they that the flex container  behave similar to a block element and the flex item like a inline block.

This is also shown in your 1st replicated sample, where neither the flex item nor the inner most `div`'s have a set width, so the inner most `div`'s content will define the width of the flex item, in the same way a nested `div` in a `div` would, where the outer `div` is set to `display: inline-block`.

---

Here is some good resources:

- https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#box-model
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

---

*Updated*

Note, a flex item can at the same time also be a flex container, like in below sample

```html
<div style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
  <div style="display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-grow: 1; ">
    <div style="flex-basis: 100%; background: red">Item 1</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; background: red">Item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```